# Array To String Conversion error from a double array

Tags: php, arrays, double

I am trying to do a double array  to echo out "brown dog" and "white cat". I got an "Array to string conversion" error on the line where I am trying to echo out the statement. How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance. Below is my code:

```
<?
$pet1 = "dog";
$pet2 = "cat";

$arrayvalue = array();
$arrayvalue[0] = array("brown, "white");
$arrayvalue[1] = array("$pet1", "$pet2");

foreach($arrayvalue as $array)
{
echo "$arrayvalue[0] &nbsp $arrayvalue[1] </br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is with a `for` loop. If you need to keep the current structure as it is, do this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) 
    echo $arrayvalue[0][$i] . ' ' . $arrayvalue[1][$i] . '<br>';
```

Here is how I would rewrite the program, keeping the current array structure and using the above `for` loop to solve your problem:

```
$pet1 = 'dog';
$pet2 = 'cat';

$arrayvalue = array(
    array('brown', 'white'),
    array($pet1, $pet2)
);

for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) 
    echo $arrayvalue[0][$i] . ' ' . $arrayvalue[1][$i] . '<br>';
```

Output:

```
brown dog
white cat
```

Comment: thanks mark.. after double checking just to make sure the word combos are in the right order... this works very well.. thanks for the code and catching the code error from the other code.. saved me a lot of time and confusion in the future :)

Comment: one more question... how would i just echo only one part ? I tried echo $arrayvalue[0][$i] '<br>'; but that didnt work... any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: @user3595005 I assume by "one part" you mean just `brown dog` or just `white cat` ... in that case, [**have a look at this**](http://3v4l.org/6fhMY), it should be helpful :)

Comment: hi... everything is well understood...thanks for the tutorial... mark... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the foreach loop a little. Also, there's a problem with your quotes above. Try:

```
<?
$pet1 = "dog";
$pet2 = "cat";

$arrayvalue = array();
$arrayvalue[0] = array("brown", "white");
$arrayvalue[1] = array("$pet1", "$pet2");

foreach( $arrayvalue[0] as $key => $color ) {
   echo "$color &nbsp $arrayvalue[1][$key] </br>";
}
?>
```

Basically instead of iterating through $arrayvalue, you should be going through the one with the colors or the one with the pets. In my example, I go through the one with the colors, and then reference the one with the pets, using `$key` to keep them in sync.

If possible, I would recommend using two separate arrays instead of one, or naming it more logically:

```
$array['colors'] = array("brown", "white");
$array['pets'] = array("$pet1", "$pet2");
foreach( $array['colors'] as $key => $color ) {
   echo "$color &nbsp $array['pets'][$key] </br>";
}

//or

$colors = array("brown", "white");
$pets = array("$pet1", "$pet2");
foreach( $colors as $key => $color ) {
   echo "$color &nbsp $pets[$key] </br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `$arrayvalue` inside your foreach loop, when you should be using `$array`

```
foreach($arrayvalue as $array)
{
    echo "{$array[0]} &nbsp {$array[1]} </br>";
}
```

Comment: @user3595005 How does this work in regards to your question? This will print `brown  white </br> dog  cat` [**See example here**](http://codepad.org/uq5YMfsX)

Comment: woah...good catch... i was just happy to see 2 lines being echo out i didnt double check if it were the right word combinations... you are right it echo the words in the wrong order... thanks for the catch.. i will review the other codes.. thanks :)